# How to get custom post meta in wp media js

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type and on the admin edit post screen I'm using wp.media  to attach the track to the post. And I'm attaching some post meta to that track also.
Is there easy way to force wp.media JS returns track with meta data?

```
trackMediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( { ... } );

trackMediaUploader.on( 'select', () => {
  const attachment = trackMediaUploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
  // want to get post meta of this attachment
  console.log( attachment );
});
```

I've tried to use `wp_get_attachment_metadata` filter, but it's wont works with wp.media js:

```
function add_attachment_metadata( $data, $id ) {
    $lyrics = get_post_meta( $id, '_track_lyrics', true );
    if( $lyrics ) {
        $data[ 'track-lyrics' ] = $lyrics;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_prepare_attachment_for_js](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/) hook:

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'prepare_attachment_for_js', 10, 3 );

function prepare_attachment_for_js(  $response, $attachment, $meta ) {
    $response[ 'trackLyrics' ] = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_track_lyrics', true );
    return $response;
}
// in admin js: 
trackMediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( { ... } );

trackMediaUploader.on( 'select', () => {
  const attachment = trackMediaUploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
  console.log( attachment.trackLyrics );
});
```